# Pig: Get first occurrence of variable in a group (while aggregating other variables)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a dataset that looks like

```
gr    col1  col2
A     2    'haha'
A     4    'haha'
A     3    'haha'
B     5    'hoho'
B     1    'hoho'
```

as you can see, in each group `gr` there is a numeric variable `col1` and some string variable `col2` **that is the same within each group.**

How can I get the following pseudo-code in PIG?

```
foreach group gt : generate the mean of col1 and get the first occurrence of col2
```

so output would look like

```
gr    mean  name
A     3    'haha'
B     3    'hoho'
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY gr,col2 and get the AVG of col1. Assuming the fields are tab separated.

**PigScript**

```
A = load 'test6.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (gr:chararray,col1:int,col2:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (gr,col2);
C = FOREACH B  GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (gr,name),AVG(A.col1) as mean;
DUMP C;
```

Note: if you want them in the order then add extra step

```
D = FOREACH C  GENERATE $0 as gr,$2 as mean,$1 as name;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: excellent thanks! could you just explain what the `FLATTEN` operator is doing here?

Comment: @Noobie It is uncoupling the group to the fields gr,name since we grouped the data on those two fields.If you don;t then you will see (A,'haha') as 1 field.